# Why I can not use the hidden permissions in android.Manifest.permission

Tags: android, permissions

I declared a permission which is hidden in the class android.Manifest.permission. It seems useless as the securityException gets thrown. Why is that? How can I use the hidden permissions?

Comment: which hidden permission? There are probably other checks guarding the calls that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that?

Some permissions require your app to be signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware.

Other permissions require your app to either be signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware, or to be installed on the system partition (e.g., by a rooted device user).

Ordinary SDK apps cannot hold these permissions. Unfortunately, the JavaDocs does not explain which permissions have which requirements.

If you look at [the platform manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), those permissions with `signature` as part of their `android:protectionLevel` allow apps to hold that permission if they were signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware. Those with `system` as part of the `android:protectionLevel` can be held by apps installed in the system partition.

So, for example:

```
<!-- Required to be able to reboot the device. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"
    android:label="@string/permlab_reboot"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_reboot"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system" />
```

This permission can be held by apps signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware *or* installed on the system partition.

```
<!-- Required to be able to disable the device (very dangerous!). -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.BRICK"
    android:label="@string/permlab_brick"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_brick"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

This permission can only be held by apps signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware.